# Cannot Refer to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am creating a Windows application the will access a sharepoint website.
There for I need to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime.dll in project.

I have add them in my references but cannot use it. Can someone help me?

Please see the issue here: [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzGgK.png)

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://hp");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: It tells you in the bottom of the image that it relies on System.Web which is not in whatever version of .NET you're targeting (it wants 4.0). You'll need to change your project to rely on .NET 4.0 if possible and add a reference to System.Web. Are you targeting 4.0 Client Profile?

Comment: Try changing the target version to .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 4.0 Client

Comment: Is there an echo in here?

Comment: here....here....here.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom of your screenshot tells you explicitly what is wrong. You seem to be targeting .NET 4.0 Client Profile which does not contain a reference for System.Web which is a dependency of the SharePoint Client.

Re-target your project for .NET 4.0.

If you're using Visual Studio go to Project > Properties > Application > Target Framework > Change it to 4.0 (NOT Client Profile)

[image]

Comment: Glad I can help. Don't forget to click the green tick and accept when you have time ;-)